# How to install an extension function on a streaming replica postgresql database?

Tags: postgresql

I am using Postgresql 9.3.

We are using [Streaming Replication](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Streaming_Replication), and I would like to use the [fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/fuzzystrmatch.html) module. I have tried to install it using [`CREATE EXTENSION`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createextension.html) but cannot because the replicated database is in read-only mode. Here is an example of my attempt:

```
=> CREATE EXTENSION fuzzystrmatch;
ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE EXTENSION in a read-only transaction
```

I tried setting the transaction mode without success:

```
=> set transaction read write;
ERROR:  cannot set transaction read-write mode during recovery
```

Is it even possible to add extensions to a replicated database? If so, how do I do it? And where in the documentation does it talk about this? Thank you!

Comment: Install it in the primary database, and it should be replicated just like anything else.

Comment: But be aware that some extensions rely on shared library code that needs to be available on the replica and may need to be loaded in the postgresql.conf too